# Coq & Emacs: Cannot compile Coq - No such file or directory

Tags: emacs, compilation, coq

When I try to compile a Coq file using C-c in Emacs, I get this error:

```
    Coq compilation error: ((coqdep -Q /home/****/cs54 DMFP /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqUMWPyn.v) No such file or directory
```

I'm on manjaro and have installed Emacs and Coq through the command line and don't know what's going on.

_CoqProject only contains these characters:

```
   -Q . DMFP
```

In case this helps narrow it down, when I type coqc into the terminal, nothing happens and the prompt comes up again.

When I type coqtop the program starts but it does not evaluate anything. When I type something like "2" or "Check 2" it simply pulls up the prompt for the next input.

Comment: Does  `coqc -v` returns something ? Did you get Coq through `opam` (OCaml package manager) ?

Comment: `coqc -v` returns `The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.13.2 (November 2021) compiled on Nov 6 2021 17:15:31 with OCaml 4.10.0`. I got Coq through snaps as directed on the main Coq website.

Comment: What happens if you compile your project using `coq_makefile` and `make`?

Comment: Trying `make` gives `bash: make: command not found`. `coq_makefile` results in a lot of text but at the end it says `Warning: no common logical root
Warning: in such case INSTALLDEFAULTROOT must be defined
Warning: the install-doc target is going to install files
Warning: in orphan_`

Comment: You could consider installing `make`, but I believe it's not the issue here. The error message mentions `proof-general`, which is a emacs interface for multiple proof assistants, including Coq. You should install it (following the instructions at : https://proofgeneral.github.io/).

Comment: @RabbitAngstrom I have not tried to run the Coq snap, but I've seen people having strange issues with it. In any case, I would try to run the following steps. (1) Install make (if you are on Ubuntu, you can run `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, it seems). (2) Use `coq_makefile` to generate a `Makefile` to compile the project. From the project's directory, type `coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile`. (3) run `make`.

Comment: @RabbitAngstrom Also, do you know exactly what command you were trying to run in Emacs? Usually, in Coq scripts, `C-c` is only part of a command, not a command by itself. (You can find out the name of the command by hitting `C-h k` and then typing the command.)

Comment: The command bound to be `C-c <return>` is `company-coq-proof-goto-point`.

Comment: @cbl proof-general has already been installed as the installation commands were already in the init.el file I was provided.

Comment: In addition, my .v file compiles successfully using CoqIDE.

Comment: I've removed the line `From Coq Require Export String.` from the given .v file and it does compile normally up to the point where the .v file uses the string type! Now the question is what went wrong in that line? It compiles successfully in CoqIDE.

Comment: Could you craft a minimal example ? :) So we could figure out if the issue comes from your installation or from the content of the project ?

Comment: I am unsure how I would go about it, but here is the link to the project file I used: [link](https://cs.pomona.edu/classes/cs54/book/Intro.v)